# Issue running find command in python with subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

I know this question has been asked few times already, just couldn't see what's wrong with my usage.

Usage#1

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/find', '/path/to/dir', '-type', 'f', '-name', '"*.gradle"', '-exec', 'grep', '"KEYWORD"', '{}', '/dev/null', ';'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, error = proc.communicate()
Error: doesn't list any files.
```

Usage#2

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/find', '/path/to/dir', '-type', 'f', '-name', '"*.gradle"', '-exec', 'grep', '"KEYWORD"', '{}', '/dev/null', '\\;'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, error = proc.communicate()
Error: find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
```

Usage#3

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/find', '/path/to/dir', '-type', 'f', '-name', '"*.gradle"', '-exec', 'grep', '"KEYWORD"', '{}', '/dev/null', '\;'], stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, error = proc.communicate()
Error: find: -exec: no terminating ";" or "+"
```

I could get the command working with the shell=True option. However, would like to avoid it as a best practice.

Command works fine when run from the shell.

```
/usr/bin/find /path/to/dir -type f -name "*.gradle" -exec grep "KEYWORD" {} /dev/null \;
```

Python Version : 2.7.11
OS X 10.11.3

Appreciate any pointers on how to get this working.

Comment: Better to assign your long command to first a variable and then pass it as a parameter to `Popen`

Comment: @ChandaKorat - Tried that, but to no avail

Comment: Exactly what is your command. can u specify as a `string`?

Comment: Why is it a 'best practice' to not use the shell keyword argument?

Comment: @ChandaKorat - Included sample command which runs fine from the shell

Comment: @VasiliSyrakis - " the use of shell=True is strongly discouraged" as noted in   https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html

Comment: @ragesh have you tried with `check_call`?

Comment: @ChandaKorat - check_call is not useful as I need output and error both. More from the python docs "Do not use stdout=PIPE or stderr=PIPE with this function as that can deadlock based on the child process output volume. Use Popen with the communicate() method when you need pipes."

Comment: @ChandaKorat - it doesn't work

Comment: @ragesh see the below answer

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to use shell escapes when you build a command as list to use with `Popen`, so in this case `\;` would be interpreted as a literal backslash followed by a semicolon, while `find` expect to see only a semicolon as single argument. Also `"KEYWORD"` will include the quotes and therefore not find `KEYWORD` without surrounding quotes. Similar for `"*.gradle"`, that will only match for filenames enclosed in quotes.

```
proc = subprocess.Popen(['/usr/bin/find', '/path/to/dir', '-type', 'f',
                         '-name', '*.gradle', '-exec', 'grep', 'KEYWORD',
                         '{}', '/dev/null', ';'],
                         stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! it worked :) Quoting the KEYWORD turned out to be the problem.

Comment: Just one hint: adding `/dev/null` as input file for `grep` seems unneccessary, it only has the effect of making `grep` prepend printed lines with the filename, which you can also achieve by usig the `-H` (`--with-filename`) flag.

Comment: Yes, that looks neat. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
cmd='/usr/bin/find /path/to/dir -type f -name "*.gradle" -exec grep "KEYWORD" {} /dev/null \;'
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=PIPE, stderr=PIPE)
output, error = proc.communicate()
```